# Custom IRouteConstraint: Return custom response instead of 404[NotFound]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd like to create a custom IRouteConstraint to check a parameter value. If that fails I'd like return 404[BadRequest] with `ProblemDetails` as body.

Something like this ;-)

```cs
public class CountryRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly List<string> _countryCodes = new() { "AF", "AX", "AL", "DZ", "AS", "AD", "AO" /*...*/ };

    public bool Match(HttpContext context, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var value);

        var country = (value as string ?? string.Empty).ToUpper();
        // If a company is required: We assume a valid value as mandatory!
        if (_countryCodes.Contains(country))
            return true;

        return new ProblemDetails
        {
            Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            Title = $@"No valid country provided: ""{country}""",
            Instance = context?.Request.Path
        };
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Ok you can only return bool obviously

Comment: "*Don't use constraints for input validation. If constraints are used for input validation, invalid input results in a 404 Not Found response. Invalid input should produce a 400 Bad Request with an appropriate error message. Route constraints are used to disambiguate similar routes, not to validate the inputs for a particular route.*" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-constraint-reference

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for the reminder. But what would be the best substitute?

Comment: [IRouteConstraint.Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint.match?view=netframework-4.8) can return a bool result and you may change the `httpContext` to realize your goal.